# Unexpected results using eval() in R

Tags: r

I have a column called "`equation`" which stored formuala about "`t`". Another column is "`t`". I want to calculate the equation's value (`y`) according to each `t` in the row. Below is an example.

```
library(magrittr);library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(t = c(1,2,3),
                 equation = c("t+1", "5*t", "t^3"))

dt %<>% 
  mutate(y = eval(parse(text = equation)))
```

However, the results seem not expected:

```
  t equation  y
  1      t+1  1
  2      5*t  8
  3      t^3 27
```

The expected results for y is: `2, 10, 27`. What should I do to fix it (but the third `y` is correct)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `eval(parse())` isn't vectorised. You can get around this using `rowwise()`:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dt <- data.frame(
  t = c(1,2,3),
  equation = c("t+1", "5*t", "t^3")
)

dt %<>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y = eval(parse(text = equation))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       t equation     y
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 t+1          2
#> 2     2 5*t         10
#> 3     3 t^3         27
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>